# ONVIF IP-camera Europe

Tags: camera, wireless

I am looking for an IP-camera model that is cheap, I can order from Europe and most importantly supports the ONVIF standard. The quality of the camera does not matter as it will be used for motion detection or as a light sensor.

I can find an IP-camera in the price range I am looking for (less than 50€), but I am not at all certain whether they have ONVIF support. ZBravo cameras claim to have it, but I couldn't find it on the list below, and I would have to order them form China.

http://www.onvif.org/ConformantProducts/ProfileProducts.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I consulted with a colleague who works with Onvif, and this is what she said:

**ZBravo is not an ONVIF member and does not have any cameras listed in the ONVIF conformant product list. Therefore, their cameras CANNOT be ONVIF conformant.**

Watch this [Onvif Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T_LebO7TtNk) for more information.

As for camera, there are a lot of cameras that are cheap and support Onvif.
But I would recommend a better suited one, but they might be a bit more pricy.

What do you mean with Light sensor? to check for light conditions? Day or Night? or the amount of light in the area of the camera?

[AXIS M1034-W](http://www.axis.com/products/axis-m1034-w)
[AXIS M3044-V](http://www.axis.com/products/axis-m1034-w)